# Unidentified Tidentifier in Ruby Block

Tags: ruby, syntax, block

I have the following code which is supposed to take in a string of letters, check which are not in between a - m and return that amount of the total length of the string e.g "3/56"

```
def printer_error(s)
  arr =  s.split('')
  count = 0
  arr.each {|item| item.include?("n".."z") count += 1}
  return count.to_s + "/" + arr.length.to_s
end
```

I am getting the following error when attempting to run:

```
-e:5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
 arr.each {|item| item.include?("n".."z") count += 1}
                                            ^
```

I am unsure what my error is here as I have gone through my syntax and do not see any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move things around a little:

```
arr.each { |item| count += 1 if ("n".."z").include?(item) }
```

Comment: Thank you this worked!

Is there a certain set of guidelines for syntax that I should use within blocks?

Comment: @John - No special syntax in blocks. They are just blocks of Ruby code. Get the Ruby right and you're there.